# Issue with inheritance in Python with Kivy

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, kivy

I have this app that has two classes, one for each screen: one SIGNIN screen and one TEST screen. In the SIGNIN class, the app takes the email address from text input and use it to create a database for the user.
I want to use the text input again in the TEST class, so I thought I could inherit from my SIGNIN class. Right now, both classes inherit from the Screen class from kivy. So I figured that my TEST class should inherit only from the SIGNIN class. But if I do this, I inherit from the entire screen: I have both screens superimposed over each other. Ultimately, I only want to get the value inside of the user variable from the SIGNIN class. How can I do that? Below is an example of what I have. I want to access the content of table_name in the second class.

```
class SigninWindows(Screen):

    def add_user(self):
        uname = self.ids.username_field.text
        table_name = uname.replace('@', '_').replace('.', '_') 

class QuestionWindows(Screen):

    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(QuestionWindows, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def _get_df(self):
        try:
            conn = pymysql.connect(
                host=hostname,
                port=int(port),
                user=user,
                passwd=passwd,
                db=db,
                charset='utf8mb4'
            )
            query = (""" SELECT * FROM db.`%s` """ % table_name)
            print('QUERY IS:',query)
```

```
<SigninWindows>:
    id: signin_page
    name: "signin_page"
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: 10
    space_x: self.size[0]/5.5
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,0,0,1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    BoxLayout:
        id: data_signin
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_x: 1
        BoxLayout:
            id: validate_info
            orientation: "vertical"
            size_hint: 1,0.8
            padding: 80, 10
            Label:
                id: info
                text: ''
                markup: True
            TextInput:
                id: username_field
                hint_text: "Username"
                hint_text_color: 0.5,0.5,0.5,1
                multiline: False
                focus: True
                on_text_validate: pwd_field.focus = True
                size_hint: 1, .8
                foreground_color: 0.5,0.5,0.5,1
                background_color: .1,.1,.1,1
                write_tab: False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this code, but if you modify `add_user()` to return `table_name`, then you can use that to get `table_name` in the `QuestionWidows` by accessing it through the `ScreenManager.get_screen()` method:

```
class SigninWindows(Screen):

    def add_user(self):
        uname = self.ids.username_field.text
        table_name = uname.replace('@', '_').replace('.', '_') 
        return table_name

class QuestionWindows(Screen):

    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(QuestionWindows, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def _get_df(self):
        table_name = self.manager.get_screen('signin_page').add_user()
        try:
            conn = pymysql.connect(
                host=hostname,
                port=int(port),
                user=user,
                passwd=passwd,
                db=db,
                charset='utf8mb4'
            )
            query = (""" SELECT * FROM db.`%s` """ % table_name)
            print('QUERY IS:',query)
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help again.